# How to remove the extra message while doing contract validate in corda

Tags: validation, corda, contract

How to remove the extra message while doing contract validate. A message should not be included

```
("net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractRejection: Contract verification failed: Failed requirement:")
```

Comment: Hey Dev - this message seems to indicate that your contract verification is failing. Are you trying to configure this to fail silently? Need more clarification here if possible.

Comment: Hi @NicholasRogers Yes my contract verification is failing and message occurred like "net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractRejection: Contract verification failed: Failed requirement: Please enter vaild email address"  but i don't want to extra message while my verification failed. It should be only that "Please enter valid email address"

Comment: Hi @NicholasRogers One more point i would like to let you know that this issue is occurred through swagger.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question and clarification above.

Corda appends this:

```
"net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionVerificationException$ContractRejection:
```

to the message as part of best practice for logging errors in a Java application. In order to remove this from the logs, you would need to slightly modify your contract - you could do something like this.

```
 if (isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
      System.out.println("Invalid Email Address")
      "Invalid Email Address" using (isValidEmail(emailAddress)
 }
```

Ultimately I assume your CorDapp will be consumed by another application, at which point you can further specify the behavior if an error is thrown. An example would be:

```
Front End --> Makes HTTP request --> API

API --> RPC communication --> Node

Node --> Runs Contract and throws TransactionVerificationException

Node --> RPC communication (Sends error back) --> API 

API --> Sends a custom message back --> Front End 

Front End --> Displays: "Invalid Email Address"
```